# Python: Building nested dictionary and iterate over - best way to accomplish this?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, loops

I am working with csv files to extract data and put them in a dictionary for analysis purpose. 
CSV files are in a directories and there are multiple csv files in each of these directories:

```
Example:
Dir: X has several csv files, file name can be X-ax-somefile.csv, X-bx-somefile2.csv
csv files have the header: level,user-id
```

I build a dictionary to store the data and while doing some calculations. At the end of this, I will end up with a following data structure:

```
{'de': {'en': {'level1': 0, 'level2': 0, 'level3': 10}}, 'en': {'si': {'level2': 1, 'level3': 5, 'level5': 5, 'levelN': 5}, 'en': {'level1': 0}, 'ta': {'level1': 1, 'level2': 1, 'level3': 1, 'level4': 5}}}
```

I wrote following code to iterate over this data structure but, is this the best way to iterate and further down in this questions I have shown how I build the data structure and is this the best way to build the data structure.

Here is my code:

```
for lang1, lang2_dict in template_count.iteritems():
    if type(lang2_dict):
        for lang2, values in lang2_dict.iteritems():
            print lang2, values
```

This is how I build the dictionary:

```
def templateUserCountStats(template_file, csv_file):
    template_count_dict = dict()
    for lang in getLanguageCodes(csv_file):
        template_count_dict[lang] = dict()
        lang_dir = os.path.join(template_file, lang)
        try:
            for filename in os.listdir(lang_dir):
                path = os.path.join(lang_dir, filename)
                if re.search(r'-.+-template-users-data.csv$',filename):
                    lang2 = filename.split("-")[1]
                    with open(path, 'rb') as template_user_data_file:
                        try:
                            reader = csv.reader(template_user_data_file)
                            reader.next()
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2] = dict()
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level1'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level2'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level3'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level4'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level5'] = 0
                            template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['levelN'] = 0
                            print filename
                            for row in reader:
                                if int(row[0]) == 1:
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level1'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level1'] + 1
                                if int(row[0]) == 2:
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level2'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level2'] + 1
                                if int(row[0]) == 3:
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level3'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level3'] + 1
                                if int(row[0]) == 4:
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level4'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level4'] + 1
                                if int(row[0]) == 5:
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level5'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['level5'] + 1
                                if row[0] == 'N':
                                    template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['levelN'] = template_count_dict[lang][lang2]['levelN'] + 1
                        except csv.ERROR as e:
                                logging.error(e)
                else:
                    continue
        except Exception, e:
            logging.exception(e)
    return template_count_dict
```

In addition to I am open for suggestions respect to building this data structure is much more pythonic way, if you need how here is a sample:

```
level,user-id
1,25
1,74
1,105
3,708
3,530
3,2568
3,2730
3,2730
2,376
2,371
2,2317
2,2095
N,560
N,110
N,119
N,1059
N,1625
```

Comment: `lang2_dict.iteritmes()` Spelling mistake, should be `lang2_dict.iteritems()`

Comment: I change the question after your comment thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"? Do you mean in terms of speed, memory usage, code readability or maintainability, aesthetics, or something else? In other words, what problem do you currently have that you would like to solve?